# How to name specific HTTP resource?

Tags: http

I can't figure out metaphor for HTTP Resource, which's content you can acquire using request with specific URI, HTTP method and headers.

I cannot use words "Resource" and "End point", because they encapsulate only URI, but not, for example, HTTP method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is "representation". See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#representations